# Putting Intent calls in a separate Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to put all my `Intent` calls in a separate class than my main `Activity` class for organization purposes. Easy enough.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class IntentCalls {


    Activity activity;

    IntentCalls(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;   
    }


    public void startIntent() {
        ...
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, _int);

    }


}
```

So, I'll be able to call startIntent() from my main Activity... But How can I set up an `onActivityResult` method in this class without making it an Activity? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your onActivityResult() method will be invoked in the activity you are passing to the constructor. So you still need to implement (override) the onActivityResult() method in the original activity. This class that you are creating is like a macro really – a convenience. From my experience I would discourage you from doing this and moving out something as trivial as this.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably more trouble than it's worth.